# How to hide Calenderview from DatePicker in API 21

Tags: android, datepicker, android-5.0-lollipop

I found that in API 21 `android:calendarViewShown="false"` is not working, Is there any other method to hide calenderView? or it is a bug?

This is how I declared DatePicker in my code.

```
        <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/dp_start_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
        ></DatePicker>
```

Comment: Are you also declaring `spinnersShown="false"`?

Comment: No. I haven't declared that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `android:datePickerMode="spinner"`. As it's an API 21 attribute, don't forget to make a new `layout-v21` folder in your `res` folder.

```
<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/dp_start_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:datePickerMode="spinner"
    android:calendarViewShown="false" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how missed that :P

Answer (score 0):

No, It's not a bug buddy.
`android:calendarViewShown="false"` is working fine on both Android 5.0 as well as on 5.0.1.

Comment: I am getting calender after writing above shown code.

Comment: It's not possible bro. It might be some other bug in your code. Because i have tried this code and its not a bug from API side at all. I have checked this on live device also which has android OS 5.0